# GCP: Is it possible to copy / transfer Objects from a source BUCKET to a target BUCKET created in a DIFFERENT Organizations?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, vpc

I have some buckets with several files in one SOURCE Project (name it: PROJECT A, created in a ORGANIZATION A), and I need to copy / transfer those source files to a TARGET Bucket (located in another Project, in a different Org. Name it: PROJECT B, created in a ORGANIZATION B).

Is it possible to use "gsutil" to copy files between buckets located in DIFFERENTS organizations (as the previous scenario) ?

Another question related to it, is:

Is it possible to created a VPC or SHARED VPC in GCP, which could "link" projects from two or more ORGANIZATIONS. I mean, I already know that one SHARED VPC can integrate MULTIPLE PROJECTS within the same Organization, but the question is whether a Shared VPC can include projects from two or more Organizations (not just one) ?

The final goal is to find a workaround to copy / transfer objects, from one bucket to another one (created in a different GCP organization).

Is that possible ?

or

The only way to achieve it, is to download the source files to local disk, and then upload them to the target bucket ?

thanks a lot, beforehand...

Comment: Howdy ... I'd strongly recommend that you split the question into two questions ... one that queries the Cloud Storage copy question and the other that relates to VPC ... these are completely different domains and (to the best of my knowledge) don't relate.

Comment: For copying files using gsutil ... my understanding is that copying from a source bucket (ANY source bucket) to a destination bucket (ANY destination bucket) is governed by IAM permissions exclusively.  The organization that owns the project that owns the bucket doesn't play into the story OTHER than providing the default permissions on the buckets when created.  As long as you have permissions to read object from the source bucket and write objects to the target bucket, I believe a copy should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Kolvan:

That was a really useful answer.

From your info, I gave IAM permission (Storage object viewer on source buckets and Storage object creator on target bucket) to the IAM user: on both source and tarjet organization. After that I am able to transfer the CSV files (500 Gb in less than 10 minutes, which satisfies the requirement).

gsutil ls -r $source_bucket/*.csv | gsutil -m cp -I $target_bucket

Regarding to the Shared VPC question, agree, I will open a separate question.

Thanks a lot!
Jose

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it here: https://console.cloud.google.com/transfer/create

[image: screenshot]

It'll allow you to selected between different projects in different organisations or even S3 etc.